# bash alias with argument and autocompletion

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of scripts in directory that exists on the path, so 
I can access each wherever I am. Sometime those are very simple util scripts that
"vims" the file. From time to time I would like to quickly see the content of script file and see path to file the script opens (then make cat, grep ...).

I would like to make an alias which will "cat" given script wherever I am.
Given one is not working:

    `` alias a="cat `which \$1`" ``

If I place script name instead of parameter number($1) it works fine. But 
with parameter not.

The second question (I wish life be so so beautiful!)   would be getting
auto-completion of script name for that alias.
Using a script that could exist in my "bin" directory would another approach which I can take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your function is called "foo" then your completion function could look like this:

If you have the Bash completion package installed:

```
_foo () { local cur; cur=$(_get_cword); COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -c -- $cur ) ); return 0; }
```

If you don't:

```
_foo () { local cur; cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}; COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -c -- $cur ) ); return 0; }
```

Then to enable it:

```
complete -F _foo foo
```

The command `compgen -c` will cause the completions to include all commands on your system.

Your function "foo" could look like this:

```
foo () { cat $(type -P "$@"; }
```

which would `cat` one or more files whose names are passed as arguments.

Comment: :-) Thanks a lot for the post. I did not accept answer before hoping to find a while to test it. What I am looking foward.

Answer (score 6):

For the alias with argument, use [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) instead of aliases :

```
a() { cat `which $1` ;}
```

Or if you do it on more than one line, skip th semicolon :

```
a() {
    cat `which $1`
}
```

You can enter it interactively at the shell prompt :

```
shell:>a() {
>cat `which $1`
>}
shell:>
```

Comment: +1 I have such solution. Be my Hero and tell me about auto completion for that function. So I do not have to input command every time by hand. Now I have auto completion when I invoke the commands that are in the path.