# Alias with Argument in Bash - Mac

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

Hi there trying to add an argument to an alias in bash. I'm using a Mac. I've searched a number of related questions:
[Alias in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in), [Alias in Bash with autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778065/bash-alias-with-argument-and-autocompletion), and a few others yet still can't sort this out. I know I need to use a function to create an alias that takes an input but it's unclear if its meant to look like any of the below options. All inputs in .bash_profile.

```
function mins_ago () { `expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* "$1"`; }

alias mins_ago = function mins_ago () { `expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* "$1"`; }

alias mins_ago = "function mins_ago () { `expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* "$1"`; }"

alias mins_ago = function mins_ago () { `expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* $1`; }
```

None of these seem to work. I either get a syntax error or it doesn't recognize the argument.

What is the actual line you'd put in `.bash_profile` to sort this properly? Thank you in advance. Is the `alias` bit included or do I just proceed to the function definition?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash aliases don't support arguments, so you need to use a bash function, and use the `bash` arithmetic operator `$(())`

```
function mins_ago() {
    printf "%s" "$(( $(date +%s) - (60 * $1) ))"
}
```

Add the above function in `.bash_profile`, and now testing it in the command-line,

```
date +%s
1485414114

value="$(mins_ago 3)"
printf "%s\n" "$value"
1485413834
```

(or) without a temporary variable to convert to readable format in `GNU date`, do

```
printf "%s\n" "$(date -d@$(mins_ago 3))"
```

Comment: I'm running what you posted above. Ah! `source ~/.bash_profile` didn't take for some reason, but exiting and trying again worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: @HectorOfTroy407: Happy to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

add this to your `.bashrc` and source it

```
mins_ago() {
  if [[ $@ != "" ]]; then
    command expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* "$@"
  else
    command echo "command error: mins_ago <integer>"
  fi
}
```

output:

```
$ mins_ago 1
1485414404
$ mins_ago
command error: mins_ago <integer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```
mins_ago () {
 `expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* "$1"`; 
}
```

It works for GNU bash 4.1.2:

```
$ mins_ago 5
bash: 1485411776: command not found
```

To avoid the error, use echo:

```
mins_ago () {
 echo `expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* "$1"` 
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding `echo`, remove the backquotes.

Comment: `-bash: /Users/CloudFlare/.bash_profile: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `{`expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* $1`'
-bash: /Users/CloudFlare/.bash_profile: line 13: `function _hours(){`expr $(date +%s) - 60 \* $1`;} _hours '` when i try `mins_ago () {
  expr $(date +%s - 60 \* "$1";
}`

Comment: @HectorOfTroy407: Can you try my answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backticks from your first try, and you should be fine.

The function will then output the timestamp, and you can write `echo "$(mins_ago)"`.